# Lambda to compose lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates

I tried to write a function in C++ which can compose a variable amount of lambdas. My first attempt kind of works (even though I suspect it isn't perfect)

```
template <typename F, typename G> auto compose(F f, G g) {
  return
      [f, g](auto &&...xs) { return g(f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...)); };
}

template <typename F, typename G, typename... Fs>
auto pipe(F f, G g, Fs... fs) {
  if constexpr (sizeof...(fs) > 0) {
    auto fg = compose(f, g);
    return pipe(fg, fs...);
  } else {
    return compose(f, g);
  }
}

int main() {

  auto add_x = [](const auto &x) {
    return [x](auto y) {
      std::cout << "+" << x << std::endl;
      return y + x;
    };
  };

  auto to_str = [](const auto &s) {
    std::cout << "to_str" << std::endl;
    return std::string("String:") + std::to_string(s);
  };

  auto add_1 = add_x(1);
  auto add_2 = add_x(2);
  auto add_3 = add_x(3);

  auto piped = pipe(add_1, add_2, add_3, to_str);

  auto x = piped(3);

  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

However, I'd like to have the `pipe` function itself to be a lambda function. This is kind of hard however, since, as I understood it, lambdas can't capture themselves. This makes simply "lambdafying" my template function problematic. Does anyone have an alternative approach or an idea how to get similar results with a lambda function?

Comment: Recursion with lambda can be "done" with `auto lambda = [](auto self, auto... args){ self(self, args...); };` and then `lambda(lambda, 42);`.

Comment: Can you please add the desired usage of `pipe` as lambda?

Comment: The general case of what @Jarod42 is describing is the [y combinator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0200r0.html)

Comment: why would `pipe` need to capture itself? Currently it is a function without state, so it isnt obvious what you want to capture

Comment: @Quimby sometimes it's useful to have a object with a template `operator()` instead of a function template

Comment: Notice that `compose` is not a lambda neither...

Comment: You may watch C++ Weekly - Ep 162 - Recursive Lambdas by Jason turner 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_Mrk1xHMoo
it will be very helpful for you

Comment: @Caleth I understand that, I do not know why it has to be a lambda instead of ordinary class or how the author wants to exactly use it w.r.t capturing.

Comment: @Quimby I'm guessing that op tried to do `auto pipe = [pipe](auto f, auto g, auto... fs) {...}` and [found that that failed](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60060f0b1a4b7949), and thus they think that capturing *something* is required

Comment: @Quimby I'm working on a project where I'm only allowed to make changes on a member-function level. Hence I can't define free functions or new classes to solve this without much trouble.

Comment: @stuckprogrammersad That's a *strange* restriction. Talk to the person who instituted that, and see if you can change it. Do they realise that lambda expressions define classes?

Comment: @stuckprogrammersad Not allowed to create new functions and classes? That's weird, but fair enough. Although `compose` is already a free function, right?

Comment: @Quimby Well, I was going to make `compose` that a lambda aswell

Comment: @Caleth I guess I could do that and after some arguing I would be allowed to implement it in another way. This Question was just me: 1. trying to take the easy way 2. being interested in the language and if something like this is even possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the y combinator to make a recursive lambda.

```
template<class Fun>
class y_combinator_result {
    Fun fun_;
public:
    template<class T>
    explicit y_combinator_result(T &&fun): fun_(std::forward<T>(fun)) {}

    template<class ...Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&...args) {
        return fun_(std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class Fun>
decltype(auto) y_combinator(Fun &&fun) {
    return y_combinator_result<std::decay_t<Fun>>(std::forward<Fun>(fun));
}

template <typename F, typename G> auto compose(F f, G g) {
  return
      [f, g](auto &&...xs) { return g(f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...)); };
}

auto pipe = y_combinator([](auto self, auto f, auto g, auto... fs){
  if constexpr (sizeof...(fs) > 0) {
    auto fg = compose(f, g);
    return self(fg, fs...);
  } else {
    return compose(f, g);
  }
});
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec3eb271b1d6c66f)

Comment: Thanks. I guess, that's the closest I will get to the desired behavior in the boundaries of what's possible. Do you have any further sources to read more about that concept in a C++ related way?